# Does pygtk support absolute positioning?

Tags: pygtk, gtk

I just want to put an Image on a screen given the X and Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a GtkFixed container to absolute position inside a GtkWindow

If you want to absolute position the toplevel window itself use gtk_window_move().